# Do you say "when I'm going to do something" in place of "when I do something"?

Tags: conjunctions, future-constructions

The following is excerpted from Unit 25 of "English Grammar in Use" by Raymond Murphy:

> Amy is on a train. She's calling a friend.
> "I'll call you again later when I arrive."
> ...
> We say
>   when I do something (not will do)
>   when something happens (not will happen)

## Question

Do you say "when I'm going to do something" in this sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the text book says, the tense in the "when" clause is simple present when referring to the future.  You don't need and shouldn't use any of the future tenses in the "when" clause.